# URL Suffix Management with YII2 is causing error

Tags: url-rewriting, yii2, suffix, yii2-urlmanager

I am facing an issue in my YII2 project. I am adding the URL suffix in the rules and it is throwing me 404 error. I don't know why i am facing this issue. Let me share my url Manager rule

```
 'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'suffix' => '.html',
        'rules' => [
            'login'=>'userportal/default/login',
        ],
    ],
```

If i remove suffix or comment that line my web application will run fine. But if with this code the web application throws 404 error.

I am using xampp on my localhost with apache server.

The .htaccess in web folder looks like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php/ - [L,R=404]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Do let me know what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You could try  'enableStrictParsing' => false,

Comment: Did that no use. I am using Apache on my localhost. Is there any issue with apache htacess?? is there any issue ?

Comment: never happen in Yii1.x

Comment: you can try with <root_url>/login.html

Comment: localhost:8080/login.html

not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:(Working solution)

**Basic app**

**config/web.php**

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'suffix' => '.html',
            'rules' => [
                '<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>',
                '<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'site/<action>/<id>',
            ],
        ],
```

**app/web/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

To access your action you simply use `login.html` and it will render `site/login` action. To be able to properly render your url, use `Url` helper like this:

```
Url::toRoute('site/login')
```

it will generate proper link using the desired extension:

```
login.html
```

Also here is the documentation with more tricks on how to manage url's in yii2 application.[Routing and URL Creation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing)

Comment: Show error log from app/runtime/logs/app.log